# Hibernate search to work on the same index for two different Entity objects

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lucene, hibernate-search

Two different entities pointing to the same Table in the database, can hibernate search create and manage a single index for both of them, since technically they point to the same table? In my scenario, two different indexes are created. How can I tell hibernate search to work on the same index

Person1.java

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index = "com.Company.Person")
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    Long id;

   @Field
   @Column(name = "NAME_FIRST_KEY")
   String firstKey;
}
```

Person2.java

```
    @Entity
    @Indexed(index = "com.Company.Person")
    @Table(name = "Person")
    public class WritablePerson
    {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
        Long id;

        @Field
        @Column(name = "NAME_FIRST_KEY")
        String firstKey; 
    }
```

I already have both classes pointed to the same index "com.Company.Person", but it still separates them based on _hibernate_class within the index.

The reason I have two entities pointing to the same table is that, in our production code we have two different entities. One for write and the other for read. So I want my indexes to be in sync.

If I use the same entity for read and write then everything works as expected.
But is there any other way to have the above scenario working?

Comment: Have you considered using many-to-one table?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have two different entities for writing and reading the same table? I imagine you're implementing CQRS, but I thought it was generally implemented at a higher level: have a single low-level, JPA-annotated, model that fits your database closely, and then have two different, higher-level query and command models on top of it using the appropriate representation, for example using automatic object mappers such as [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/). Is it not what is usually done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you write to the database, you use the `WritablePerson` entity type, thus the `_hibernate_class` field is set to `org.company.WritablePerson`, but when searching you want to get results of type `org.company.Person`, for the same documents that were originally written as `org.company.WritablePerson`.

There's no built-in support for that. There are, however, ways to do it yourself; you will (sadly) have to re-implement parts of what Hibernate Search usually provides out of the box, and may also lose some of the performance optimizations we implemented for object loading, but it should be possible.

The idea would be, essentially, to perform a projection query on the ID, and then load the entities corresponding to those IDs explicitly:

```
List<Person> myQueryMethod(<some params>) {
    FullTextEntityManager em = ...;
    Query luceneQuery = ...;
    FullTextQuery query = em.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, WriteablePerson.class );
    query.setProjection( org.hibernate.search.engine.ProjectionConstants.ID );
    List<Object[]> projections = query.getResultList();
    return loadResults( Person.class, projections );
}

<T> List<T> loadResults(Class<T> clazz, List<Object[]> idProjections) {
    List<Serializable> ids = new ArrayList<>( idProjections.size() );
    for ( Object[] projection : idProjections ) {
        ids.add( (Serializable) projection[0] );
    }
    return em.unwrap( Session.class ).byMultipleIds( clazz )
        .with( CacheMode.<pick a cache mode> ) // May be ommitted
        .withBatchSize( <pick a batch size> ) // May be ommitted
        .multiLoad( ids );
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for your help! We will of course look into whether this is a doable solution or if we need to take another route for efficiency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Your options with Hibernate Search do not depend on how entities are mapped on the database, that's an entirely orthogonal aspect.

You can have [multiple entities share the same index](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-sharing-indexes), regardless of how they are stored in the same table or not.

You can also have one entity [sharded across multiple indexes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#advanced-features-sharding).

And finally, you can even [use some entity property as discriminator across shards](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter-shard) so that specific kinds of filtering can benefit from the physical index storage to match a favourite filter.

The *_hibernate_class* field is a technical detail which shouldn't have any impact if you have no other entities, but it might become essential if you in future decide to add another entity into the same index, and mapped to a different table.

Comment: I am not sure if that's the case, I believe what Logan has here is that, when he uses Person2 entity to write to DB, would he be able to read it via Person1 entity?

Comment: ah, right I misunderstood that. That's a very interesting question then.